# Wipe disk with bad sectors

Tags: dd, disk, corruption, data, badblocks

I'm trying to wipe a bad disk using `dd` with the following command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda status=progress`, but it exits prematurely and outputs the following:

```
13160186368 bytes (13 GB, 12 GiB) copied, 481 s, 27.4 MB/s 
dd: writing to '/dev/sda': Input/output error
25753561+0 records in
25753560+0 records out
13185822720 bytes (13 GB, 12 GiB) copied, 490.915 s, 26.9 MB/s
```

How do I get it to ignore I/O errors and continue till the end? If `dd` isn't able to do this, is there another program that can?

**EDIT #1**

I'm using `dd` from a Linux live CD

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229356/30851

Comment: If you are wiping the disk to throw it away, just destroy it physically. A couple of holes in the patter area with an electric drill is enough.

Comment: Future readers, I found a disk wipe utility in the BIOS which worked as required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore write errors while zeroing a disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229354/how-to-ignore-write-errors-while-zeroing-a-disk)

Comment: @legends2k Maybe, don't have a need for it at the moment though.